# JavaFX ListView NullPointerException

Tags: java, javafx

При вызове модального окна невозможно взаимодействовать с ListView, ошибка NullPointerException

**Вызов модального окна:**

```
  SelectAlbums selectAlbums = new SelectAlbums();
  selectAlbums.SetAlbums(actionEvent, albumsList);
```

***actionEvent*** передается от нажатой кнопки, ***albumsList*** уже хранит список List со значениями

**Код модального окна:**

```
public class SelectAlbums {

    @FXML
    ListView<String> VIewAlbums;

    private ObservableList obsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    public SelectAlbums(){}

    public void SetAlbums(javafx.event.ActionEvent actionEvent, List albumslist){
        try {

            Stage stage = new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("albums.fxml"));
            stage.setTitle("Выбор альбома");
            stage.setMinHeight(500);
            stage.setMinWidth(400);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            stage.initOwner(((Node)
            actionEvent.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
            stage.show();
            PutAlbum(albumslist);


        }catch (Exception E){E.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public void PutAlbum(List Albums){
        obsList.setAll(Albums);
        VIewAlbums.setItems(obsList);
        VIewAlbums.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**FXML файл модального окна:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="333.0" prefWidth="458.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.company.SelectAlbums">
   <children>
      <ListView fx:id="VIewAlbums" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="312.0" prefWidth="408.0" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="11.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="21.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="29.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создали экземпляр класса `SelectAlbums_1`, запустили в нем метод set, который задал параметры окна и отобразил окно, подготовив для работы с ним экземпляр `SelectAlbums_2`. Далее, отобразив сцену, вы положили ваши альбомы в `SelectAlbums_1`, который не имеет никакого отношения к GUI и `VIewAlbums` не был инициализирован (отсюда NPE).
FXMLoader внутри класса используется, когда вы создаете собственный переопределенный контрол, но тогда конструкция имеет несколько другой вид

```
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("albums.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    fxmlLoader.load();
```

Как правило, генерация окна происходит в месте, которое вызывает открытие этого окна и 
содержимое `SetAlbums` проще перенести вместо строчки `SelectAlbums selectAlbums = new SelectAlbums();`